# Getting "Cannot find HTTP header here" in play framework Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I have the following code in my class.

```
def authenticateUser() = CouchbaseAction("Knr"){ implicit request =>
    var finalResult = Json.obj()

    val (username, password) = loginForm.bindFromRequest.get
}
```

When I ran this it gives an error:

```
Cannot find HTTP header here
```

on `loginForm.bindFromRequest.get`

Yesterday I tried to use Javascript routes but I have now removed everything. Before adding the Javascript routes it worked properly. What may cause the problem?

Comment: Add tag to your question with exact Play version (like _playframework-2.x_)

Comment: What's the type of `implicit request`?

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
def authenticateUser() = CouchbaseAction("Knr"){ implicit request =>
    var finalResult = Json.obj()

    val (username, password) = loginForm.bindFromRequest(request).get
}
```

This makes the request explicit instead of implicit.